# How to make the extjs accordion layout example dynamic?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've pulled out the accordion layout .html and .js files from the **extjs examples** (below).

What is the **next step** to make this dynamic e.g. how the syntax of a link looks so that the HTML that fills a section under a panel on the left has links which fill the content on the right.

**Does anyone know of tutorials which go beyond this shell and show how to make it dynamic, i.e. integrate it in a working application?**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Accordion Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css"/>

    <!-- GC -->
    <!-- LIBS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <!-- ENDLIBS -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            font: normal 12px verdana;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0 none;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .empty .x-panel-body {
            padding-top:20px;
            text-align:center;
            font-style:italic;
            color: gray;
            font-size:11px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function() {

            var item1 = new Ext.Panel({
                title: 'Start',
                html: '&lt;this is the start content&gt;',
                cls:'empty'
            });

            var item2 = new Ext.Panel({
                title: 'Application',
                html: '&lt;empty panel&gt;',
                cls:'empty'
            });

            var item3 = new Ext.Panel({
                title: 'Module',
                html: '&lt;empty panel&gt;',
                cls:'empty'
            });



            var accordion = new Ext.Panel({
                region:'west',
                margins:'5 0 5 5',
                split:true,
                width: 210,
                layout:'accordion',
                items: [item1, item2, item3]
            });

            var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
                layout:'border',
                items:[
                    accordion, {
                    region:'center',
                    margins:'5 5 5 0',
                    cls:'empty',
                    bodyStyle:'background:#f1f1f1',
                    html:'This is where the content goes for each selection.'
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shared/examples.js"></script><!-- EXAMPLES -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a billion ways to do it. The question is vague... but here's a very simplistic one. Just have an Ajax function that calls the server and adds the panels dynamically. 
Say your server provides the following JSON, by calling /links.json

```
{links: ['http://www.google.com'], ['http://www.yahoo.com']}
```

You would do the following

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        var accordion = new Ext.Panel({
            region:'west',
            margins:'5 0 5 5',
            split:true,
            width: 210,
            layout:'accordion'
        });

        new Ext.Viewport({
            layout:'border',
            items:[
              accordion, 
              {region:'center', html:'This is where the content goes for each selection.'}]
        });

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/links.json',
            callback: function(response) {
                var json = Ext.decode(response);
                var cfgs = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < json.links.length; i++) {
                    cfgs.push({
                        html: json.links[i]
                    })
                }
                accordion.add(cfgs);
            }
        });            
    });
```

But there's nothing that I coded here that you didn't already know, is there?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good source of information that will probably help you get forward:
[Saki's Ext Examples Page](http://examples.extjs.eu/).